# How to use numpy to flip this array?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

Suppose I have an array like this:

```
a = array([[[ 29,  29,  27],
            [ 36,  38,  40],
            [ 86,  88,  89]],
           [[200, 200, 198],
            [199, 199, 197]
            [194, 194, 194]]])
```

and I want to flip the 3rd element from left to right in the list-of-lists so it will become like this:

```
b = array([[[ 29,  29,  89],     # 27 became 89
            [ 36,  38,  40],
            [ 86,  88,  27]],    # 89 became 27
           [[200, 200, 194],     # 198 became 194
            [199, 199, 197],
            [194, 194, 198]]])   # 194 became 198
```

I looked up the NumPy manual but I still cannot figure out a solution. `.flip` and `.fliplr` look suitable in this case, but how do I use them?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a 3D array? Your syntax is wrong.

Comment: Yes, it is. My bad, I edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Index the array to select the sub-array, using:

```
> a[:,:,-1]
array([[198, 197, 194],
       [ 27,  40,  89]])
```

This selects the last element along the 3rd dimension of `a`.  The sub-array is of shape `(2,3)`.  Then reverse the selection using:

```
a[:,:,-1][:,::-1]
```

The second slice, `[:,::-1]`, takes everything along the first dimension as-is (`[:]`), and all of the elements along the second dimension, but reversed (`[::-1]`).  The slice syntax is basically saying start at the first element, go the last element (`[:]`), but do it in the reverse order (`[::-1]`).  You could pseudo-code write it as `[start here : end here : use this step size]`.  The the `-1` tells it walk backwards.

And assign it to the first slice of the original array.  This updates/overwrites the original value of `a`

```
a[:,:,-1] = a[:,:,-1][:,::-1]

> a
array([[[ 29,  29,  89],
        [ 36,  38,  40],
        [ 86,  88,  27]],

       [[200, 200, 194],
        [199, 199, 197],
        [194, 194, 198]]])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you explain a little more about the [:,::-1] part in a[:,:,-1][:,::-1]? I am try to figure out how can this code will reverse the order..

Comment: The RHS could be written as `a[:, ::-1, -1]`, selecting the last column, and reversing the rows at the same time.

Comment: I see! This is very clever!